# namecheap actionmailer setup not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, namecheap

First post on SO
I have set up a basic contact form using actionmailer which I had working perfectly with gmail. I then set up a private email with Namecheap and then implemented the relevant details. Unfortunately, no emails send and I get an authentication error.

535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:

My setup is as follows

```html
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'mail.privateemail.com.',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'domain_name',
  user_name: ENV['NAMECHEAP_EMAIL'],
  password: ENV['NAMECHEAP_PASSWORD'],
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this post. The code above is actually correct. I had a misspelling in the password I was serving to namecheap. Settings work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, port 587 worked like a charm for me. As per the Namecheap docs [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1179/2175/general-private-email-configuration-for-mail-clients-and-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Email services often have authentication settings that bar unknown apps from logging in to your account, which is what your error indicates. For Gmail, this setting is called "Allow less secure apps" and it needs to be turned on for email to a mailer to work. There should be a similar setting for Namecheap.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Port 26. According to this blog. https://www.bitesite.ca/blog/ruby-on-rails-actionmailer-configuration-for-namecheap-private-e-mail

This is a known issue with namecheap.

Comment: @MateMrše This answer looks just fine to me - all the essential information (use port 26 instead) is included in it.